# How and What would be the best module in Python to populate a list from Excel based on another column?

Tags: python, excel, automation

I want to get the values from one column based on their values in another column of the same worksheet.

Is xlrd/Openpyxl best or should I use pandas?

I need to perform a repetitive task for the data that will populate the list

Thank you

Comment: `pandas`. Happy to help!

Comment: Thank you! I'm a noob to coding so sorry if the question was dumb.